# How do I add a value to existing array of JSON file in Node JS

Tags: arrays, json, node.js

I'm having an existing JSON file and data is like this.

```
[{"address":"unit f 11-13 short street, auburn, nsw 2144"},{"address":"village green brooks circuit, lidcombe, nsw 2141"}]
```

I want to add a new value to this JSON file. This is my method.

```
function saveNewAddress(
  address /* :?string | void */, cb
) /* :Promise<string> */ {


  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fs.appendFile('address-list.json', JSON.stringify(address), "utf8", function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("File saved.");
}); 

});

}
```

This works but it doesn't add the new value to the array. It's adding the new value to the end of the array.

Comment: In case of JSON I would suggest you read JSON file, parse it's string format to JSON, then simply add data to parsed object  using array.push in this case, then re-write all data to JSON again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `fs.appendFile()`, the data is added at the end of the file as a string, not as a new array element.

You need to get the content of your JSON file as a JavaScript object, add the property to the array and finally save the new file.

One way to do it is to read the file with `fs.readFile()`, like suggested by TGW in his comment.
However NodesJS has a convenient method to do that with `require()`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const json = require('./address-list.json');

function saveNewAddress(address) {    
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    json.push({address})    
    fs.writeFile('address-list.json', JSON.stringify(json), (err) => {
      if (err) reject(err)
      resolve("File saved.")
    })
  });
}

saveNewAddress('some_new_adress')
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result) 
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works. I'm totally new to node and all. Can you please explain what do you mean by here ('some_new_adress')? is it passing the new address?

Comment: Your _saveNewAddress()_ function expects a string (or undefined) as input, 'some_new_adress' is just an example of an address that you add to your JSON file: `[..., {"address":"some_new_adress" }]`.